# How to solve this top bar problem on SwiftUI, elegantly?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to use the whole iPhone area for my app.

I have this HStack at the top, used to create a custom toolbar.

```
var body: some View {

  VStack (spacing:0) {
  
    MyTopbar()
    // other controls

    Spacer()
  }
  .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

This appears like this on new devices with a notch and old devices without a notch. The notch cuts my menu.

[image]

I can solve that by adding a spacer with a frame height before `MyTopbar()` on the vertical stack but first of all this seems to be a very awful solution. First I have to guess a height for that spacer. Then I have to detect if the device has a notch or not (?).

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you sure that `MyTopbar` (or any container up the hierarchy) doesn't `ignoresSafeArea()`? Because I can see that by default your `VStack` should be respecting the safe area and handle this case for you automatically.

Comment: VStack is the one that ignores the safe are but like I said, I am trying to use all area for the app

Comment: I might be understanding this poorly, but what you describe is something that _respects_ the (top) safe area layout guide (your top bar) and other content that doesn't (anything that you want full screen above or below your bar - but not in the same container). For example a `ZStack` where the "bg" does ignore and the topbar doesn't). I hope that this makes sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of it as layers (content that respects safe area and content that doesn't).

Something like this perhaps:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea() // Whatever view fills the whole screen

            VStack (spacing:0) {
                MyTopbar()
                // other controls
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to add clear color with safe area height. No need for much calculation.

```
var body: some View {

  VStack (spacing:0) {
    Color.clear.frame(height: Color.clear.frame(height: UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0)
    MyTopbar()
    // other controls

    Spacer()
  }
  .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```